# Pointer Array Question

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Creating an array can be done both of these ways? But isn't all an array is the beginning of the array address and allocate enough bytes for the type. So my question is what's the difference either using a pointer to an array of bytes or using just the first option?

```
int numbers[10];

int* num = new int[10];
or
int* num = new int(10);
```

Comment: There are several duplicates, but I'm too lazy to go and find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second version there declares a pointer to an integer initialised to 10. That's not an array.

Answer (score 4):

`int array[10];` has two different behaviors. Used inside a function, it will allocate 10 uninitialized ints on the stack. Outside a function, it will allocate 10 zero-initialized ints in BSS memory.

`new int[10];` allocates ten uninitialized ints on the heap.

`new int(10);` allocates a single int on the heap, with value 10.

Comment: `int array[10]` has a third meaning inside a parameter list. There **and only there**, it is just syntactic vinegar for `int* array`. That is, you cannot pass arrays by value in C++.